# Should a button in a Laravel project trigger methods in the Controller and if so, how

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-5.3

I'm new to Laravel and Web Development in general.

I have an `Add to cart` button in `shop.blade.php` :

```
<a href="{{url('cart')}}" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</a>
```

Then in `web.php` I have:

```
Route::get('cart', function()
{
    return View::make('pages.cart', ['active'=>'navCart']);
});
```

The button obviously redirects to the cart page when pressed.

I'm using [LaravelShoppingcart](https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart) to add items to my cart.  To add an item I can use code like:

```
Cart::add('192ao12', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);
```

What I actually want, **I think**, is some functions, presumably in a Controller (should this be injected into the View?), that I can call from buttons such as `Add to cart`, decrement "-" or increment "+".

Putting the `Cart::add` in the Route as shown below is clearly wrong but actually achieves half of what I want - the product is added to the cart (I don't actually want that button to move to the cart page).

```
Route::get('cart', function()
{
    Cart::add('192ao12', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);
    return View::make('pages.cart', ['active'=>'navCart']);
});
```

So, I'm thinking I should be calling methods in the `Controller` from the View but everyone says I shouldn't do this so what is the proper way to make the View, namely a button, affect the model in `Laravel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Define a `controller` say `CartController` and in that create function `addToCart()` and then write the code whatever you want.

like,

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function addToCart()
    {
    //Your cart related logic
    Cart::add('192ao12', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);
    return View::make('pages.cart', ['active'=>'navCart']);
    }
}
```

and then define it in your `routes/web.php` like,

```
Route::get('cart', 'CartController@addToCart');
```

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like this is the solution but I get an error in `routes/web.php`  `FatalThrowableError in web.php line 41:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ',' or ')'`  Any ideas?  Do I need to 'inject' the `CartController` in this line in `web.php` `Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');`

Comment: Cool.  That seems to fix that but now it seems `CartController` doesn't 'know about' Cart  `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Cart' not found`

Comment: You need to import it all the classes that needed for cart i.e. your logic

Comment: Thanks.  I'll mark this as correct.  I'll work out how to do that!  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Create an "addToCart" route/controller method that adds the item to the cart, this would typically add the item to the cart then redirect to the cart controller method to display the cart